# Best ways of making a 3D grid?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, landscape

What is the best way to create a 3D grid?

In java, I am making a game that takes place in a somewhat Minecraft styled world. I need a 3D grid to map out each block, and I'm still a bit confused on how I should go about putting it all in.

I am using LWJGL in hopes that it would make my life so much easier. But if there is something better to use, let me know.

A link to a downloadable minecraft world based tutorial would be wonderful! I have not been able to find any tutorials on the subject (or download-ables).

Basic World Idea:

- Makes a 3D grid 1024 x 1024 x 128
- Different block types with flexible land tops/bottoms (so the land is more "real")
- Chunk based system for land that would be grouped into 16 x 16 x 128 blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change size or implement complex logic on this grid it is better to create your own data structure based on List. But in most cases (only holding data) plain arrays are appropriate.

Comment: So would it end up being a 3 deep array? (for the x, y, and z values?)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do... where do you want to apply it?  Personally, I'm rather fond of arrays.  It is often the cheapest and most straightforward solution.

Complex data structures are usually only needed when you forsee future changes (i.e. the data structure will change, etc.)

Can you give more detail regarding the application?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a 'block' object representing a coordinate (x,y,z) in your space and your block can have members like "textureTop" and "textureBottom" and whatever else you need to draw it.

Then, since it looks like your space is fixed size just make a 3D array of them.

```
Block [] [] [] space = new Block [1024][1024][128];
```

Then if you want to make your chunks just define another object Chunk which is basically a 16x16x128 array of Blocks.